# how to remove bug character in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bug in my code and i try to remove it using jquery.

Some code:

```
<div id="content">
s
<div class="breadcrumb">
<h1>Test and etc</h1> etc etc....
```

I want to use jquery to remove the s (if exist...in some cases not)

I've tried

```
var cont = $('#content').html();

$('#content').html(cont.replace('/s\s(.*)/','$1'));
```

Seams that the code above is not working...some sugestions ?

Comment: Why can you not remove it from the HTML source directly?

Comment: You don't need the outer apostrophes when you use regex. `cont.replace(/s\s(.*)/,'$1')`. I'm not sure how well the regex itself works though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to call the code when the DOM is `ready`. And remove the quotes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cont = $('#content').html();
  $('#content').html(cont.replace(/s\s(.*)/,'$1'));
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/anj1x7xe/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex to remove a textnode by running a replace on the HTML, target the textnode directly

```
var content = document.getElementById('content'),
    child   = content.firstChild;

if (child.nodeType === 3) { // if textNode
    content.removeChild(child);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y3bnfbvn/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand, why won't you remove it directly from the HTML source?

Is the code automatically generated (aka you didn't manually write that 's' there)? Because if it is, I strongly suggest you correct the bug itself. What you're trying to do is covering up a bug, not fixing it. It's good practice to get to the source of a bug and fix it.

Alas, if you really want to do this: You need to specify when your script is called. Most likely, you want it put into the `$(document).ready()` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cont = $('#content').html();

  $('#content').html(cont.replace('/s\s(.*)/','$1'));
});
```